# Automatically create a duplicate excel file and delete its content

Tags: excel, if-statement, copy

I am exporting an excel file from a software, and the following is the picture of it:[image: Exported excel file]

Here for some fruits there is both In and Out where 1 represents In and 0 represents Out.

Here is what I want to have:
1) Delete all the rows the first two times they appear for a particular fruit. For ex: Orange is being let In (1) and let Out (0), which means we are good on that. Same goes for every other fruit. Now, another case is Apple, which is let In (1) twice, and let Out (0) only once. Here only delete the first In (1) and the first Out (0) for Apple. And finally in the case of Watermelon, nothing needs to be done because it has only been let In (1). Same three conditions apply for all the fruits.

2) Now what I talked about in step 1 needs to be done in another file. So, when this file is exported, it automatically creates a copy of itself, and inside that copy, everything I mentioned in step 1 is done.

The final result in that copied file will look like the image below:[image: Copy of the excel file]

Comment: you would need vba to do this

Comment: @gowtham could you please tell me how?

Comment: Please try googling for options. If you are not able to resolve, let me know. Glad to help.

Comment: Can I just instead have them highlighted or that will require VBA as well? Because I don't think I can learn it in the time I have.

Comment: Ok how about this. I manually filter and order all the apples for ex in a row. Now, we have to delete the first two rows for every fruit because they will have the 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in `columns A and B`, create a new column and copy the data from `column A` and remove the duplicates. (Column D for example as below)

[image]

Enter the below formula in cell `E2` and drag down,

```
=IF(ISODD(COUNTIF(A:A,D2)),1,"")
```

Then filter just `1`s from the output. This is what you need finally. If you want everything to be automatic when you export the sheet, then you need vba.

Comment: What you have provided me with is all manual. The 1's in column E are not important at that point because we know that the fruits are there because they are 1's. Please let me know if there is another way. Otherwise, thanks for your help.